# Capturing and recording touch events on UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, uievent

I'm trying to subclass UIView and design a transparent view. This view will sit on top of many other views and it's only task is to capture and record user touches (tap and pan). I have tried many different methods, explained in different questions asked by other users with no luck. This is what I have done so far in my implementation file:

```
#import "touchLayer.h"

@implementation touchLayer

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) [self commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) [self commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.alpha = 0.0;
}

- (id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
        else if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved) NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
        else if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded) NSLog(@"touchesEnded");

        return nil;
    }
    else
        return hitView;
}

@end
```

Now this code works just fine, and I see see the touches in the lower layers, but I cannot differentiate between touchBegan, touchMoved, and touchEnded. `[[event allTouches] anyObject]` returns ***nil***. Do you have any idea how I can capture tap and pan on a UIView without blocking the touches? Thanks a lot.

Comment: So now, your problem is this view block the touches in below views. Is it right?

Comment: No actually touches are passed to the lower view. However, I need to know what kind of touches (began, moved, ended) are captured by this UIView, but the event.allTouches.anyObject returns nil.

Comment: As i know, i’m sure that transparent view doesn’t receive touch. Try give it a color and you will see the difference

Comment: I have also tried it with colour and alpha channel. It does receive the touch, but like I said I cannot get the UITouchPhase. It's nil.

Comment: Try to use these 3 method `func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) `, `func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)` and `touchesEnd`

Comment: I have also tried those, they capture the touch properly, but do not pass the touch to the lower views. I add `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` to send the touch to the next view, no luck.

Comment: In a nutshell, hitTest sends the touch to the lower view just fine, but does not detect the type of touch, on the other hand, touchesBegan, touchesMoved, ... detect the type of touch correctly, but do not pass the touch to the lower view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating, actually i can't find solution to detect touch using `hitTest` method with a `touchLayer`. But your question is about capturing and recording user touches, so i have another for this issue.

My solution is

- Subclass `UIWindow`
- Replace `window` of `UIAppDelegate` with a new one which is created with your window class.
- Override `sendEvent` method of `UIWindow`, capture and record user touches in this method.

This is my subclass of `UIWindow` to detect touch. I tried and it work.

```
@implementation DetectTouchWindow

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

  switch ([touch phase]) {
    case UITouchPhaseBegan:
      NSLog(@"Touch Began");
      break;
    case UITouchPhaseMoved:
      NSLog(@"Touch Move");
      break;
    case UITouchPhaseEnded:
      NSLog(@"Touch End");
      break;
    case UITouchPhaseCancelled:
      NSLog(@"Touch Cancelled");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end
```

For more detail and easier, i created a demo repo to check it. You can take a look at this link https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/recording-touch-events

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for sharing this. Works like a charm.

Comment: Welcome @BabakSamareh ;)

Comment: On a separate note, I also have to record touches in different view controllers. This method that you suggested starts capturing touches from the moment the app is opened until it's closed. How can I differentiate between touches captured for different view controllers?

Comment: You can use `UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController` to check what is current controller ;)

Comment: @BabakSamareh or in `DetectTouchWindow`, just use `self.rootViewCont‌​roller`

Comment: Welcome my friend ;)

Comment: Quick question @trungduc, since you are an expert in UITouch, and just for my own knowledge, is there anyway that I can implement this on a UIView? It will give me more flexibility in what I'm trying to achieve. Is there any sendEvent method for UIView that I can use? Or any other way to capture tap and pan and then pass them on to the lower view? I have tried hitTest, but the UIEvent returned by hitTest does not contain touch information!

Comment: For your question: 1. Is there any sendEvent method for UIView that I can use? - I'm afraid that answer is no because `sendEvent` is a method of `UIWindow` not `UIView`. 2. Any other way to capture tap and pan and then pass them on to the lower view? - I think you can use `UIGesture` or `touchBegin`, `touchMove` without `layerView` ;)

Comment: Aren't those blocking the touches? For example, if I override touchesBegan and then touch a UIButton, will it receive the touch?

Comment: Of course, let try. I think it still receives touch.

Comment: I'll try and update the answer here. Thank you again for your time and support :)